# How can i run reader process and writer x times

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm trying to build a new springbatch application in order to save a part of oracle data into elastic search.

To do that, i have build a new project with RepositoryItemReader, ItemProcessor and RepositoryItemWriter.

But when i start my application my 3 steps are run one after the other. In fact, i want run this 3 steps for each page request of my RepositoryItemReader.

This is mys job :

```
@Bean
  public Job importPurchase(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step importPurchaseStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory
        .get("importJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(importPurchaseStep)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step importPurchaseStep(
      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
      ItemReader<PurchaseEntity> purchaseItemReader,
      ItemWriter<Purchase> purchaseItemWriter,
      TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("importPurchaseStep")
        .chunk(1000)
        .reader(purchaseItemReader)
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(purchaseItemWriter)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
        .throttleLimit(20)
        .build();
  }
```

I would like springbatch to read the 1000 elements on page 1, then transform them in the processor, then write them in the writer. And then it does the same for page 2...

Is it possible to do that automatically with spring batch ?

Comment: just add three seperate flows

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: after your .start, you add a .next and you add the next flow/step there

Comment: hum. Thank you for your response but i think my message is not clear. In fact i read a lot of data from a database (reader) and i just want to write them group by 1000 items. So i can't add manually a lot of step because number of step depends of my reader. Do you understand my problem ?

Comment: then  dabble around with chunksize and such configurations of your reader.